# MYSQL WHERE clause in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php file that display all artists that I have in my table, and its working fine. I am just trying to display particalar artists with specific condition, for example displaying only artists where their city is Baltimore. I am not good at php and would like to get some help.

```
<?php 
    $page_title = 'Browse the Prints';
    include ('includes/browse_style.html');
    require ('../mydesigner/mysqli_connect.php');
    // Default query for this page:
    $q = "SELECT artists.artist_id, CONCAT_WS(' ', artist_name) AS artist, print_name, price, description, print_id FROM artists, prints WHERE artists.artist_id = prints.artist_id ORDER BY artists.artist_name ASC, prints.print_name ASC";
    // Are we looking at a particular artist?
    if (isset($_GET['aid']) && filter_var($_GET['aid'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array('min_range' => 1))  ) {
        // Overwrite the query:
        $q = "SELECT artists.artist_id, CONCAT_WS(' ', artist_name, artist_city, artist_type, artist_mobile) AS artist, print_name, price, description, print_id FROM artists, prints WHERE artists.artist_id=prints.artist_id AND prints.artist_id={$_GET['aid']} ORDER BY prints.print_name";
    }

    // Create the table head:
    echo "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://www.lectmohd.com/mydesigner/includes/css/table2.css' />"; 
    echo '<table border="0" width="90%" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3" align="center">
        <tr>

            <th align="left" width="10%">السعر</b></th>
            <th align="right" width="40%">الوصف</th>
            <th align="right" width="20%">إسم التصميم</th>
            <th align="right" width="20%">المصمم</th>
        </tr>';
    // Display all the prints, linked to URLs:
    $r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

        // Display each record:
        echo "\t<tr>

            <td align=\"right\">\${$row['price']}</td>
            <td align=\"right\">{$row['description']}</td>
            <td align=\"right\"><a href=\"view_print.php?pid={$row['print_id']}\">{$row['print_name']}</a></td>
            <td align=\"right\"><a href=\"browse_prints.php?aid={$row['artist_id']}\">{$row['artist']}</a></td>
        </tr>\n";

    } // End of while loop.

    echo '</table>';
    mysqli_close($dbc);
    include ('includes/footer.html');
?>
```

Comment: `WHERE artist.city = 'Baltimore'`. What is your question exactly? Where are you stuck?

Comment: My question its that, I only want to display artists with specific cities. I know how to do that in Mysql, but don't know where i should put the statement in the php file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add condition with city

```
WHERE artists.artist_id = prints.artist_id AND artists.artist_city = 'Baltimore'
```

Comment: Thank you for you response, but where in the file should I add this condition?